# Any Android app that can set "Always on Display" mode for JUST notifications?

Tags: android, notification, display

> Typically, an Ambient display solution which turns on the screen only when notifications are present, remains on, but turns off when they are dismissed.
>
> <sup>- [Always on Display, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Always_on_Display)</sup>

This feature is meant to show you which notifications you got piled up at any given time. Once you handle them, the phone's screen goes off again.

Unfortunately some phones don't seem to have such a native option ([*cough* Nokia 9 PureView *cough*](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230890/how-to-enable-an-always-on-display-mode-in-nokia-9-for-just-notifications)), so is there an app that can do it for them?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of what your looking for: [Notify Buddy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xander.android.notifybuddy).  It won't show the entire notification, but it will alert you that there is one.

Comment: This app is for [Notification LED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notification_LED), which is the predecessor to Always on Display. Any chance there's also an AoD app out there? If not, what does Notify Buddy mean by "Disable Ambient Display" and will this LED indeed remain on until I handle my notifications?

Comment: I believe "Disable Ambient Display" means turn off AoD in settings.  This app is quite customizable, you can change the size of the notification LED, make the LED blink, and much more.  It should stay on until the notification is removed.  I think you should try it and see if it will work for your needs.

Comment: I installed it but when trying to give it notification permissions the phone warned me **"NotifyBuddy will be able to read all notifications, including personal information, such as contact names and the text of messages you receive. It will also be able to dismiss notificaitons or trigger action buttons they contain"**. That's a bit too rich for my blood...

Comment: Yeah I feel the same way.  But unfortunately any notification AoD app will need that permission.

Comment: How unfortunate. I was hoping for an indirect approach of "you have notifications, we don't know which, but we just know you have something to review..." In the case of Nokia 9 above, I was thinking about an app which would trigger Glance view every once in a while...